# Recuperar imagem do Firebase Storage sem fazer download

Tags: firebase, ionic2

Eu fiz o uso do Firebase Storage para salvar imagens, agora eu quero pega-las para os usuários verem, tem algum jeito de fazer isso **sem fazer download da imagem?**

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso da seguinte forma:

```
            refEst = storageRef.child('estabelecimentos').child(id + '.png');
            refEst.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                return url;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("erro");
            });
```

Comment: Olá amigo. Tenho varias imagens na pasta dessa forma só pega uma. Como faria pra listar todas?

Answer (score 0):

O método taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() foi removido nas versões recentes do Firebase Storage SDK. Você precisará obter o URL de download no StorageReference agora.

Chamar StorageReference.getDownloadUrl() retorna uma Task , pois precisa recuperar a URL de download do servidor. Portanto, você precisará de um ouvinte de conclusão para obter o URL real.

Eu fiz dessa forma e deu certo:

private void salvarFotoStorage(String urlString, final int tamanhoLista, int contador){

```
    //Cria o nó storage
    StorageReference imagemAnuncio = storage.child("imagens").child("anuncios").child(anuncio.getIdAnuncio()).child("imagem"+contador);

    //Fazer upload do arquivo
    final UploadTask uploadTask = imagemAnuncio.putFile(Uri.parse(urlString));
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String urlConvertida = uri.toString();
                            Log.i("UPLOAD",  urlConvertida);


                            listaUrlFotos.add(urlConvertida);

                            if(tamanhoLista == listaUrlFotos.size()){
                                anuncio.setFotos(listaUrlFotos);
                                anuncio.salvar();

                                dialog.dismiss();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("DOWNLOAD", "FALHA AO CAPTURAR DOWNLOAD"+e.getMessage());
                }
            });



        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            exibirMensagemErro("Falha ao fazer upload");
            Log.i("UPLOAD", "FALHA NO UPLOAD"+e.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```